# NEST Elasticsearch C# - Issue MAPPING NESTED Index multiple bahaviours

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nested, nest, elastic-stack

I might have something wrong with my code because this same code sometimes applies the nested to my index and sometimes it doesn't.

Why?

Am I forgetting something?

.Mappings overrides annotations? Could there be any mapping conflict between annotation and `.Mappings`?

```
client = new ElasticClient(settings);

if (client.IndexExists(defaultIndexName).Exists)
            client.DeleteIndex(defaultIndexName);

client.CreateIndex(defaultIndexName, c => c
                             .Mappings(ms => ms
                                     .Map<Store>(m => m
                                         .AutoMap()                                 
                                         .Properties(p => p
                                             .Nested<Product>(n => n
                                                 .Name(nn => nn.Products)
                                                 .AutoMap()
                                                 .Properties(pps => pps
                                                   .Keyword(k => k
                                                        .Name(l => l.Label)

                                ))
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
            );
```

POCOS

```
 public class Store
 {       
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Keyword]
        public string Name{ get; set; }
        [Nested]
        public List<Product> Products{ get; set; }
    }
```

Product

```
 public class Product
    {   
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public double Price { get; set; }
        [Keyword]
        public string Label { get; set; }           
        public double Quantity { get; set; }
        public double Total { get; set; }
        public int StoreId { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: That will always apply the mapping to a newly created index. Where it won't apply is if the index already exists, which you'd be able to check because `.IsValid` will be false on the response.

Comment: ok, I didn't know that. Thanks. That explains why I was struggling to understand different behaviors symptoms. I have two additional lines  I've added to the example above where it checks if the index exists, but I thought it would check the index, and independently if it was or not created it would apply the mappings for both situations anyway.

Comment: Then, my question is, how do I guarantee the mapping to be applied with the nested type for both situations, having the index created or already with an index there? I am not sure I understood what `.isValid` would do. I researched a bit but diddn`t find. How can I use it to guarantee the mappings to be applied to any situation?

Comment: You can apply a mapping to an existing index with `.Map<T>()`, but the only way you can guarantee the mapping will be applied is before any documents are indexed into the index, since Elasticsearch will infer a mapping from the first document it sees. If you need explicit mapping, I recommend adding mapping on index creation.